# How to prove that $\max_{t} F(tu) =\frac1n\left(\frac{\|u\|^2 -\lambda|u|_2^2}{|u|_{2^*}^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded domain. Let
$$F:u\in H^1_0(\Omega)\mapsto \frac12\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 dx-\frac{\lambda}{2}\int_{\Omega} |u|^2 dx -\frac{1}{2^*}\int_{\Omega} |u|^{2^*} dx,$$
where $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $2^*=\frac{2n}{n-2}$ denotes the critical Sobolev exponent.

As an exercise, I have to prove that fixed $u\in H^1_0(\Omega), u\neq 0$
$$\max_{t} F(tu) =\frac1n\left(\frac{\|u\|^2 -\lambda|u|_2^2}{|u|_{2^*}^2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}},$$
where $\|u\|^2 =\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^2 dx$ denotes the norm in $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $|u|_r^r =\int_{\Omega} |u|^r dx$ the norm in the Lebesgue space $L^r(\Omega)$.

I am in truble about proving this thing. Firstly, I observed that
$$F(u) =\frac12 \|u\|^2 -\frac{\lambda}{2} |u|_2^2-\frac{1}{2^*}|u|_{2^*}^{2^*}.$$
I am pretty sure that somewhere the embedding $H^1_0(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^{2^*}(\Omega)$ is needed and I observed that $\left(\frac12 -\frac{1}{2^*}\right)=\frac1n$, so that $\frac1n$ which appears could be something like that.

Honestly, I don't know how to proceed. Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance!

${\bf EDIT.}$ To be more precise with notations: it is
$$|u|_{2^*}^2 =\left(\int_{\Omega} |u|^{2^*}dx\right)^{\frac{2}{2^*}}.$$

Comment: I haven't thought this fully through, but maybe it works: Using the Sobolev embeddings, you can show that the expression $F(tu)$ is bounded above, so a maximum exists. Then we can use a scaling argument and use that for the maximum, we should have $ \frac{d}{dt}F(tu)=0$ at $t=1$, if the maximum is attained at $u$. I could be totally on the wrong track though.

Comment: @F.Conrad, could you please give more details? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: Let $a,b > 0$ be given. What is the maximum of $a t^2 - b t^{2*}$ w.r.t. $t$?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}F(tu)=0 \iff t^{2^*-2}=\frac{\|u\|^2 -\lambda|u|_2^2}{|u|_{2^*}^{2^*}}$, assuming the maximum exists and is therefore a critical point. Now it should just be solving for $t$ and plugging into the expression. If it is still unclear, I can try to post an answer later this week.

Comment: @gerw if I consider $f(t) = at^2-b t^{2^*}$ and I compute the derivative, if my computations are right, i have two critical points for $t=0$ and $t=(\frac{a(n-2)}{nb})^{\frac{4}{n-2}}$. Did you mean this?

Comment: @F.Conrad why do you consider $|u|^{2^*}_{2^*}$ instead of $|u|^{2}_{2^*}$?

Comment: Isnt that what appears in $F(u)$?

Comment: @C.Bishop: Yes, this is what I mean. The approach by F. Conrad is essentially the same.

Comment: @gerw thank you for you comment. Thus the maximum should happen for $t=(\frac{a(n-2)}{nb})^{\frac{4}{n-2}}$. Anyway, I feel further away from the result (In particular, I don't understand why in the expression of the maximum it appears $|u|_{2^*}^2$ instead of $|u|_{2^*}^{2^*}$. I guess it comes from some Sobolev embedding, but I miss the details. And why the exponent is $\frac{n}{2}$ instead of$\frac{4}{n-2}$. Could you please give a hint? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @F.Conrad thank you for your comment and your time. I hope to understand it as soon as possible, so I will not ask you for more details.

Comment: You are welcome, filling in the details is sadly often really tedious :-(

Comment: @F.Conrad I just finished all the details on my own, it works! Thanks for the heads up! :)

Comment: @gerw many thanks to you, too.

Comment: You are welcome @C.Bishop! Glad it worked out.